# jQuery Closures, Loops and Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, closures

I have a question similar to the one here: [Event handlers inside a Javascript loop - need a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341723/event-handlers-inside-a-javascript-loop-need-a-closure#341759) but I'm using jQuery and the solution given seems to fire the event when it's bound rather than on click.

Here's my code:

```
for(var i in DisplayGlobals.Indicators)
{
    var div = d.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = "100%";
    td.appendChild(div);

    for(var j = 0;j<3;j++)
    {
        var test = j;
        if(DisplayGlobals.Indicators[i][j].length > 0)
        {   
             var img = d.createElement("img");
             jQuery(img).attr({
                     src : DisplayGlobals.Indicators[i][j],
                     alt : i,
                     className: "IndicatorImage"
              }).click(
                     function(indGroup,indValue){ 
                         jQuery(".IndicatorImage").removeClass("active");
                         _this.Indicator.TrueImage = DisplayGlobals.Indicators[indGroup][indValue];
                         _this.Indicator.FalseImage = DisplayGlobals.IndicatorsSpecial["BlankSmall"];
                         jQuery(this).addClass("active"); 
                     }(i,j)
               );
               div.appendChild(img);   
          }
     }
}
```

I've tried a couple of different ways without success...

The original problem was that _this.Indicator.TrueImage was always the last value because I was using the loop counters rather than parameters to choose the right image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're missing a function.  The .click function needs a function as a parameter so you need to do this:

```
.click(
    function(indGroup,indValue)
    {
        return function()
        {
            jQuery(".IndicatorImage").removeClass("active");
            _this.Indicator.TrueImage = DisplayGlobals.Indicators[indGroup][indValue];
            _this.Indicator.FalseImage = DisplayGlobals.IndicatorsSpecial["BlankSmall"];
            jQuery(this).addClass("active"); 
        }
    }(i,j);
);
```

Answer (score 13):

Solution by **Greg** is still valid, but you can do it without creating additional closure now, by utilizing `eventData` parameter of jQuery [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method (or [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) or any other event-binding method, for that matter).

```
.click({indGroup: i, indValue : j}, function(event) {
    alert(event.data.indGroup);
    alert(event.data.indValue);
    ...
});
```

Looks much simpler and probably more efficient (one less closure per iteration).

Documentation for [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method has description and some examples on event data.

Answer (score 6):

**Nikita**'s answer works fine as long as you are using jQuery 1.4.3 and later.  For versions previous to this (back to 1.0) you will have to use **[bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)** as follows:

```
.bind('click', {indGroup: i, indValue : j}, function(event) {
    alert(event.data.indGroup);
    alert(event.data.indValue);
    ...
});
```

Hope this helps anyone else still using 1.4.2 (like me)