# jQuery click event is not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple problem with the jQuery click event, which I am not able to solve.

**Here is the code:**

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var links = $('.brandLinks li a');
    console.log(links.length); // there are total 24 items are there

    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].click(function(e){
            console.log('click.');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you have `<br/>` tags in the javascript code?

Comment: ok. just for line break. if i will remove then also i am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to loop. The majority of jQuery methods will operate on *each item* in the matched set. Also, `document` shouldn't be quoted. You want to select the actual `document` object. If it's quoted, jQuery will be looking for an element with the tag name "document":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.brandLinks li a').click(function () {
        console.log('click');
    });
});
```

---

*Side note*: It doesn't actually matter that the string "document" won't match anything in this case. The `ready` method will operate on any jQuery object, regardless of what it contains (even if it's empty). It would make much more sense to others reading your code (and yourself in the future) to actually select the `document` object though. For these reasons, I usually use the alternative form:

```
$(function () {
    // This is the same as $(document).ready(function () {});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need for loop to bind event. you can bind entire elements at once. `link[index]` is native JavaScript element. You should have used `$(link[k]).click`.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var links = $('.brandLinks li a'); 
        console.log(links.length); // there are total 24 items are there 
    links.click(function(){
           console.log('click.'); 
    });         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var links = $('.brandLinks li a');
console.log(links.length); // there are total 24 items are there

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].click(function(e){
        console.log('click.');
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code was that you were not taking care of closure, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359467/jquery-closures-loops-and-events)

Following should work:

```
var link = links[i];
 $(link).click((function(value) {
                    return function() {
                      //   
                    };
                })(link));
```