# Why this mouseover script doesn't work properly?

Tags: javascript

I have written this script:

```
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++){
  if (elms[i].className == 'liitem'){
  var delete_id = elms[i].id;
  elms[i].onmouseover = function(){  
    document.getElementById("delete-" + delete_id).style.display = "block";
    }
  elms[i].onmouseout =  function(){  
    document.getElementById("delete-" + delete_id).style.display = "none";
    }
   }
}​
```

HTML:

```
<li class="liitem" id="205">
    <span>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/finance/portfolio?action=view&pid=1" target="_blank">One:</a> </span>
    <br>
    <ul><li>
        <span><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">www.google.com</a> </span><span id="delete-205" style="float:right;font-size:11px;display:none;"><a href="">delete</a></span></li></ul>
</li><br>

<li class="liitem" id="204">
    <span>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/finance/portfolio?action=view&pid=1" target="_blank">Two:</a> </span>
    <br>
    <ul><li>
        <span><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">www.google.com</a> </span><span id="delete-204" style="float:right;font-size:11px;display:none;"><a href="">delete</a></span></li></ul>
</li><br>

<li class="liitem" id="203">
    <span>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/finance/portfolio?action=view&pid=1" target="_blank">Three:</a> </span>
    <br>
    <ul><li>
        <span><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">www.google.com</a> </span><span id="delete-203" style="float:right;font-size:11px;display:none;"><a href="">delete</a></span></li></ul>
</li><br>
​
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5FBjm/1/

but it doesn't work properly.
I want that when there is mouseover on a certain `<li>` element of "liitem" class, 
then show "delete" link of that element (with the same ID).

In my script instead, appear only the last "delete". Why?

Comment: Please supply the code in your post.

Comment: Please don't use the "Format as code" option on the main text of your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event handlers inside a Javascript loop - need a closure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341723/event-handlers-inside-a-javascript-loop-need-a-closure)

Comment: To have a glimpse at native javascript, I realize it is harder to code :)

$('a').hover(function(){
   var liID = $(this).parents('.liitem').attr('id');
   $('#delete-'+liID).toggle();
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `delete_id` with `this.id` and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/5FBjm/4/

Comment: good call - didn't notice myself that it was his `id` field that had the scope problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have a variable scope problem - in the callbacks `delete_id` always has the last value assigned, not the value it had when the callback was registered.

Do a Google search for "javascript loop scope callback" for *hundreds* of examples (many of them here) on how to fix it.

---

EDIT - as @gabitzish points out, you can just use `this.id`

This only works because the browser passes the current element as `this` to the callback.

Since the loop variable you need is actually that element's `id`, you can just use it directly and not worry about the loop scope problem.  The answer above would apply if it been some other variable which isn't a property of the element.