# Dynamically generated Select-Elements and a JavaScript Closure

Tags: javascript, html, closures

I want to generate some `<select` elements dynamically. I'm copying an existing one and only change the name and the onchange-Event. This is where my problem is: Every `<select>` has its own ID. When the onChange-Event fires it should respond the Value and the ID of the Element. I don't know how to define the JavaScript Closure exactly. I tried it with "this.value", but apparently this does not work...
I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341723/event-handlers-inside-a-javascript-loop-need-a-closure) example, but it did not work for me at all :/

The JavaScript:

```
var i = 0;
var selectArray = [];

function addSelector(){

var container = document.getElementById("check0");

selectArray[i] = document.getElementsByName("select0")[0].cloneNode(true);
selectArray[i].name = 'select'+i;
selectArray[i].onchange = function(v, i) {
        return function() {
           changeType(v, i)
        }
    }(this.value, i);

container.appendChild(selectArray[i]);
}

function changeType(selected, i) {
    switch (selected) {
        case 'One':
           alert(selected+' , '+i);
            break;
        case 'Two':
            alert(selected+' , '+i);
            break;          
        case 'Three':
            alert(selected+' , '+i);
            break;
        case 'Four':
            alert(selected+' , '+i);
            break;
        case 'Five':
            alert(selected+' , '+i);
            break;
    }
}
```

(I tried to post the HTML aswell, but for some reason i wasnt able to do this ;) )

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vogti/FNFQU/)

Comment: The value of `i` is never changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.value` isn't known here:

```
function addSelector(){
    /* ... */
    selectArray[i].onchange = (function(v, i) {
        return function() {
            changeType(v, i)
        }
    })(this.value, i);
    /* ... */
}
```

`this` will be `undefined` (in strict mode) or `window` (normal mode). How should JavaScript know that `this` is a reference to the created/cloned `<select>` object? `this` will be correct inside of your `onchange`, so you don't have to include this by closure, only the index `i` has to be included:

```
selectArray[i].onchange = (function(index) {
    return function() {
        changeType(this.value, index)
    }
})(i);
```

Notice that your syntax for alert is wrong - you should use `alert(selected + " " + i)` instead, as the second argument will be ignored.

**See also:**

- [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FNFQU/12/)
- [MDN: `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Thank you, thats what I needed to know! I wasnt sure how to say the changeType "take the value of the dynamically created selector". Thats why I thought i have to set "this.value" also as an parameter...
Now it works just as i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is really hard to follow. There are a number of problems with it

- `i` is never changing
- `this.value` does not have the correct value when you call it, but it's easy to figure out from within the handler

The following script does what I think you need http://jsfiddle.net/FNFQU/13/

```
function addHandler(node, index){  
   node.onchange = function() {
      alert('Changed select index ' + index + '. Its value is ' + node.value);
   }
}

function duplicateSelectElement() {
   var container = document.getElementById("check0");
   var allSelects = document.getElementsByName("select");
   var firstSelect = allSelects[0];
   var newSelect = firstSelect.cloneNode(true);
   addHandler(newSelect, allSelects.length + 1);
   container.appendChild(newSelect);
} 

addHandler( document.getElementById('select0'), 1 );

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = duplicateSelectElement;
```

Using the following HTML

```
<input type="button"
       id="btn"
       value="Add Selector!" />
<div id="check0">
<select id="select0" name="select">
    <option selected>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
    <option>Five</option>
</select>
</div>​
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Indeed, i is never changing - I forgot to increment it.
Your Script does what I wanted, but I need to do it using closures. Thats why I set the other Answer as correct.

Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: @vogti An answer that helps you find your problem deserves an upvote. My answer does use a closure, it doesn't use a self calling anonymous function. Why would you *need* a self calling anonymous function?

Comment: Your answer might use a closure, but the other answer helped me precisely to fix my problem. Thanks a lot again, i gave you an up!

Comment: @vogti: Main reason why you shouldn't use the code you have: No need for the globals you created. Also, your `changeType` function is  badly named (it doesn't change a type) but it also doesn't need a switch: `alert(selected + ',' + i)` would do it.