# How to pass an object to an onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Event handlers inside a Javascript loop - need a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341723/event-handlers-inside-a-javascript-loop-need-a-closure)

I am getting some json object through an API call.It is of the folowing format:-

```
{data:[{id:"1",name:"some1",url:"someurl1"},{id:"2",name:"some2",url:"someurl2"}...]}
```

I get it through a jsonp result and it is parsed as below:-

```
function(results){
   for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    item=document.createElement("div");
    item.innerHTML=results.data[i].name;
    item.onclick=function(){
        console.log(results.data[i]);  //--->this is where i am stuck 
      }
    }
 }
```

How do i pass the particular object from the loop to the onclick event. I mean the first div created should have an onclick event with the data of the first object and the second div should have the data from the second object..
Please ask me if any more clarification is required

Edit:-
If I do something like this:-

```
item.onclick=function(){
  console.log(results.data[1])
}
```

I get that particular object in the onclick event of all the items , but that is not what i want

Edit:-
This is how i finally solved it. Thanks to the link pointed to by DCoder.

```
item.onclick =function(object){
           return function(){
           //do something with the object
           }

         }(obj);
```

Comment: This is the infamous Javascript closure problem.

Comment: How many times can one answer this question before going daffy?

Comment: @Shmiddty please try once more...

Comment: @DCoder that really helped.. if only you had posted this as an answer I could have accepted it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
function(results){
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
        (function(index){ // create a closure, this makes a new scope
            item=document.createElement("div");
            item.innerHTML=results.data[index].name;
            item.onclick=function(){
                console.log(results.data[index]);  //--->this is where i am stuck 
            }
        })(i);  // pass in i
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shmiddty this really is closest to how i finally solved it..

Comment: But do you understand why you were having the problem in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You could always jQuery's [data](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/data#name) function to store and retrieve the data object:

```
function(results){
  for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    item=document.createElement("div");
    item.innerHTML=results.data[i].name;

    // Store object in data 
    $(item).data("results", results.data[i]);

    item.onclick=function(){
        // Retrieve the data needed
        var data = $(this).data("results");
        console.log(data);
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The onclick event is fired from jquery when someone clicks on 'item'. You cannot expect custom data to the event handler unless it is triggered using trigger function.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into trouble with doing async calls inside of js. This is a common problem and it's describe here:
http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Advice-on-closures-and-retaining-variable-values-inside-async-handlers-e-g-xhrGet-td3227726.html

Basically the value of `i` is equal to `9` by the time your console.log is actually ran.

There are many ways to solve this problem in general, but your specific solution should probably be to restructure things immensely. Consider this alternative (requires jQuery), but we could do the same without it very easily.

```
$.each(results, function(data) {
  var $el = $("<div></div>").html(data.name).click(function() { console.log(data) });
})
```

But it would be even better to use [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store things and then use `.on()` or `.delegate()` to listen for the click events like this

```
$.each(results, function(data) {
  var $el = $("<div></div>").addClass("yourThing").html(data.name).data("data", data);
})

// replace window with a closer parent if one exists
$(window).on("click", ".yourThing", function() {
   console.log($(this).data("data")); // retrieve data from jquerys .data() store
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden field inside your div (created in loop), keep whatever you want in it.
then on click of div. find hidden field inside it(div) and read its value.

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally use [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) so the function callback creates a new execution context for each iteration.

As you've tagged the question with jQuery, your code can be as simple as

```
$($.map(data, function(v, i) {
    return $('<div>').html(data[i].name).click(function() {
        console.log(data[i]);
    });
})).appendTo('body'); //appending for demonstration purposes
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/x9gu5/)

Of course, you have to wrap it inside a function and pass the `data` array of objects as you were doing previously.