# Adding events on dynamically created tags

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating some divs in my script with a certain class name in a loop. I want to add onclick event to every div and get their innerHTML by clicking on them. but with every click I get only the last div's innerHTML. here's my code :

```js
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  var itemRow = document.createElement("div");
  itemRow.innerHTML = i;
  itemRow.onclick = function(){
    return function(){
      console.log(itemRow.innerHTML); //which now returns only the last div innerHTML
                      
    }();
  }
}
```

Thanks very much

Comment: Don't add an event to every div, this could cause performance issues with a large number of divs. Add a delegated handler with something like jquery 'on' https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass an object to an onclick event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501867/how-to-pass-an-object-to-an-onclick-event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue with for loop and event callbacks. You are trying to access a variable inside the function which will be updated by the for loop. That's why you are seeing the last div innerHTML always. Change the code to

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  var itemRow = document.createElement("div");
  itemRow.innerHTML = i;
  itemRow.onclick = getClickHandler(itemRow);

}

function getClickHandler(itemRow){
    return function(){
      console.log(itemRow.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the contents of the loop inside a [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)  function to create lexical scope so that the event handler could remember the data.

```js
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 (function(i) {
     var itemRow = document.createElement("div");
     itemRow.innerHTML = i;
     itemRow.onclick = function(){
        alert(itemRow.innerHTML); 
     }
     document.body.appendChild(itemRow);
  })(i);
}
```

Else very simple, you can just use `this.innerHTML` to get the value there. Inside the click handler, you won't have access to `itemRow` assigned to it during looping. It will always point to last element. To avoid it just use `this.innerHTML` there. Also no need to return a self executing function inside the event handler.

> EDIT: Adding demo

```js
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  var itemRow = document.createElement("div");
  itemRow.innerHTML = i;
  itemRow.onclick = function(){
      alert(this.innerHTML); 
    }
  document.body.appendChild(itemRow);
}
```

Comment: down voter could you please care to tell the reason also for the down vote. So that i can understand and correct :)

Comment: Hate it when people do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  var itemRow = document.createElement("div");
  itemRow.innerHTML = i;
  itemRow.onclick = function(){
      console.log(this.innerHTML);
  }
  document.getElementById('main').appendChild( itemRow );
}
```

Check my fiddle link below :

http://jsfiddle.net/9q1pLueq/