# Javascript undefined variable error

Tags: javascript, onclick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Event handlers inside a Javascript loop - need a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341723/event-handlers-inside-a-javascript-loop-need-a-closure)

I want to simply assign onclick events to a series of `li` elements within an unordered list. Instead of doing it the messy way by either defining lots of unique IDs and manually adding the events to each `li` element I'd like to do it programatically with a `for` loop.

html:

```
<ul id="homeNav">
    <li><a title="Back to home page" href="">home</a></li>
    <li><a title="Play" href="">play</a></li>
    <li><a title="About the site?" href="">about</a></li>
    <li><a title="Latest development news and info." href="">dev blog</a></li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var parentList = document.getElementById('homeNav');
    var listItems = parentList.getElementsByTagName('li');
    var numItems = listItems.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        listItems[i].onmouseover = function()
        {
            listItems[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.color = 'blue';
        }
        listItems[i].onmouseout = function()
        {
            listItems[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.color = '#cccccc';
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error `listItems[i] is undefined`

To me it looks like the event is literally looking for the `i` index variable instead of using the number assigned to it at the time of the event being added to the trigger, or maybe the `i` variable isn't within the closures' scope?

Comment: I'd rather not use jQuery. I'd like to be comfortably proficient with Javascript before I dabble in JS libraries and frameworks.

Comment: I just created [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PMnQr/1/) and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 because this function will never be called.

Comment: @IgorShastin gotcha, I just never experienced the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable is not avilable in the event, you can use `this`..

```
for(var i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
{
    listItems[i].onmouseover = function()
    {
        this.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.color = 'blue';
    }
    listItems[i].onmouseout = function()
    {
        this.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.color = '#cccccc';
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Works perfectly. I would have expected the JS interpreter to associate it with the `this` equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but i would think & check

```
var listItems = parentList.getElementsByTagName('li');
listItems[i]
```

...
I'm not sure that you're doing it 
2) do a console.log (listItems) to see what's it, and remember about array - object difference. that's all for now, have to go... sorry for the brief answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

there is problem in your code.  on mouseover or mouseout value of i would be  equal to numItems; as these events will get called after finish of for loop. so you should save context.

```
function bindEvent(elem){

            elem.onmouseover = function()
            {
               elem.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.color = 'blue';
            }
            elem.onmouseout = function()
            {
               elem.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.color = '#cccccc';
            }
}

    window.onload = function()
    {
        var parentList = document.getElementById('homeNav');
        var listItems = parentList.getElementsByTagName('li');
        var numItems = listItems.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
        {
          bindEvent(listItems[i]);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure? It works exactly as intended with a simple change from `listItems[i]` to `this`

Comment: using this is better. but if you want to save index of item then above will help you. both answers are correct.