# Assign onclick function in a loop does not work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, onclick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Event handlers inside a Javascript loop - need a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341723/event-handlers-inside-a-javascript-loop-need-a-closure)

I am having **hrefs** in table cells. 
I am iterating through those cells with a **'for' loop** to change the onclick function. 
But this does not work. 
Here are 2 examples:

This **works**:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length - 1; i++) { // for each row
    var len = document.getElementById("my_table").rows[i].cells.length-1;
    document.getElementById("my_table").rows[i].cells[len].innerHTML = "X1";
  }
```

This **does not work**:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) { // for each row
    var len = document.getElementById("my_table").rows[i].cells.length-1;
    document.getElementById("my_table").rows[i].cells[len].onclick = function() {
        deleteRows(i);
    };
  }
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) { // for each row
    var len = document.getElementById("my_table").rows[i].cells.length-1;
    document.getElementById("my_table").rows[i].cells[len].onclick = (function(index) { return function() {
        deleteRows(index);
    };})(i);
  }
```

Code above should work. In your case it does not works because you have a closure to `i` defined in `for (var i = 0` Basically, `i` which you pass to `deleteRows` points to `i` defined in `for` which at that moment will be equal to `tbl.rows.length` My code creates new closure for each cycle of loop. For more information google javascript closure.