# Javascript Set Dynamic Variables inside a For Loop Within addEventListener

Tags: javascript

This code works great for me but I need the two variables inside the listener to be dynamic numbers representative of the item which you clicked. Right now of course they are hard coded to "7" but all I need is to make them dynamic.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('largeItems');

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var itemWays = 7;
        var currentItem = 7;
        document.getElementById('display').src = detailsImage[itemWays];
    }, false);
}
```

I guess I would like something like this:

```
var itemWays = this.items[i]; //this.itemIndex that was clicked
var currentItem = this.items[i]; //this.itemIndex that was clicked
```

Cheers,

Comment: If I had a dollar for every "my loop and closure doesn't work".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event handlers inside a Javascript loop - need a closure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341723/event-handlers-inside-a-javascript-loop-need-a-closure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HTMLElement` is `this`. The index `i` is a bit harder to capture, since it takes on a whole bunch of values during the for loop. Wrapping it in a function to "save" its value will work.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('largeItems');

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        items[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            var itemWays = i;
            var currentItem = this;
            document.getElementById('display').src = detailsImage[itemWays];
        }, false);
    })(i);
}
```

If you are not using IE8 or below, do

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('largeItems'), function(item, i) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var itemWays = i;
        var currentItem = this;
        document.getElementById('display').src = detailsImage[itemWays];
    });
});
```