# need some explanation on this array

Tags: javascript, arrays

What kind of array is this? Can any one explain it to me? I mean I have never encountered the elements of an array initialized like this!

```
var helpText = [
          {'id': 'email', 'help': 'Your e-mail address'},
          {'id': 'name', 'help': 'Your full name'},
          {'id': 'age', 'help': 'Your age (you must be over 16)'}
        ];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event handlers inside a Javascript loop - need a closure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341723/event-handlers-inside-a-javascript-loop-need-a-closure)

Comment: It's just an array of objects; it's basic JavaScript syntax. The code won't work for reasons explained in the linked duplicate question.

Comment: As far as I understand, he asks about the data type of the values in the array, so it doesn't matter if it works or not, in this context.. Hence my answer below

Comment: I think you should learn JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

This is an **[array of objects](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=javascript%20array%20of%20objects)**..

Comment: IMHO, a link to a google search result (not even a single page) is not quite enough to consider this a valid answer.

Comment: Well, if this link (which points to Google) is ever going to be invalid then... you get my point :) Anyway what exactly would you write in here? It's as simple as it gets: Array of objects.

Comment: Point is this is a comment not an answer. OP wants an explanation this answer is not enough self-contained to provide one. Please [edit] or it might get deleted.

Comment: I realize some people can't accept the fact that **some answeres ARE short**, and rather need some amount of bullshit (within the answer's body) in order to feel warm and comfortable with it.. Please, do something better with your time guys :) And no offence really :))

Answer (score 0):

In JS there is two ways to create a new array.

With an Array constructor:

```
var helpText = new Array();
```

or with an array initializer:

```
var helpText = [];
```

Both of these snippets create a new empty array. However, it's not recommended to use the Array constructor, since a missuse of its arguments may lead to unexpected results. You can read more about arguments at [MDN: Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

When using an array initializer, you can also add members to an array:

```
var arrOfNumbers = [0, 1, 2, 4];
```

Also creating an array with a single member containing `0` is possible, unlike when using Array constructor:

```
var arrOfNumbers = [0];
```