# Not getting the correct position when assigning click listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating some div and assigning click listener to those div in a for loop
The code is like this.

```
    function selectedPhotosDiv(path){

try{

    var choiceDiv = document.createElement('div');
        choiceDiv.id = "photos"+Buttler.User.chatid;
        choiceDiv.className = "display_photos";
    for(var i=0;i<path.length;i++)
    {   
        var box = document.createElement('div');
        box.className = "img_box";
        box.id = "box"+i;
        box.style.backgroundImage="url('file://"+path[i]+"')";
        var close = document.createElement('div');
        close.className = "img_close";
        $(close).click(function(){
            console.info(i);
        });
        box.appendChild(close);
        choiceDiv.appendChild(box);
    }
    return choiceDiv;
}catch(error){
}

}
```

However on clicking the close the value of i is always the last value of i ie path.length-1;
I am not able to figure out where i am doing the mistake.
Need Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery I'd have done it like this. See http://jsfiddle.net/4ZW8A/1/

```
function selectedPhotosDiv(path){

    var $box;
    var $choiceDiv = $('<div id="photos'+ Buttler.User.chatid + '" class="display_photos" >');
    for(var i=0;i<path.length;i++)
    {   
        $box = $('<div id="box' + i + '" class="img_box" >\
                    <div class="img_close">\
                </div>');
        $box.css('background-image', "url('file://"+path[i]+"')");
        $box.find('.img_close').click(function(){
            var index = $(this).parent('.img_box').attr('id').replace('box', ''); 
            console.log(index);
        });

        $choiceDiv.append($box);
    }
    return $choiceDiv;
}
```

You can't use `i` as it's value may have been already incremented when you clicked the close.

Comment: See my edit and the fiddle

Comment: Working buddy. Thanks a lot. Can you please provide me some link to understand close and what was the actual problem was there?

Comment: See the 'duplicate of' issue. You have to understand theses concepts (there is a lot of resources on google): Javascript scope, hoising, events and callback (async behavior), etc. Or read one of those books: http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742 or http://www.amazon.com/Secrets-JavaScript-Ninja-John-Resig/dp/193398869X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1392728178&sr=1-1&keywords=Javascript+ninja

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
$(document).on('click', close, function(){
            console.info(i);
        });
```

Or you can check this topic : [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341723/event-handlers-inside-a-javascript-loop-need-a-closure)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has to do with javascript closures.
The `i` variable will always be the last value iterated over.

Change you code to this

```
$(close).click(function(){
    console.info($(this).parrent().attr("id"));
});
```

ant it should work

Comment: Here this will point to box div(as stated in code snippet above ) not close