# acessing object properties in a function inside a loop

Tags: javascript, object

i hve been trying to add the click event to the particular div created .
which was successful ,my problem is when clicked it shows me undefined.

here is the code

resulta is a global variable (array with objects)

```
for(s = 0;s<resulta.length;s++)
    {
        y = document.createElement('div')
        y.setAttribute('class', 'eachssd');
        var x = document.createTextNode(resulta[s].name)
        y.appendChild(x);
        o.appendChild(y)
        y.addEventListener('click',function bnmhv(){location.href=resulta[s].datasrc},false)
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What if you changed `y.addEventListener('click',function bnmhv(){location.href=resulta[s].datasrc},false)` to `y.addEventListener('click',function(){location.href=resulta[s].datasrc},false)` leaving the `bnmhv` out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event handlers inside a Javascript loop - need a closure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341723/event-handlers-inside-a-javascript-loop-need-a-closure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the for loop executes all created event listeners referrence the same `s` variable which, after every iteration, have value equal to `resulta.length`, so resulta[s] is indeed `undefined` and every event handler will refer to this value. What you have to do is create new scope for every of your handlers via enclosing it in closure. This scope can "hold" `resulta[<current iteration's s value>]` so that handlers can refer to it.

For example:

```
for(var s = 0; s < resulta.length; s++)
{
    (function (data) {
        var y = document.createElement('div')
        y.setAttribute('class', 'eachssd');
        var x = document.createTextNode(resulta[s].name)
        y.appendChild(x);
        o.appendChild(y)

        y.addEventListener('click', function () { location.href = data.datasrc }, false);
    }(resulta[s]));
}
```

In every iteration an [anonymous function is created and immediately invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) with one argument beeing `resulta[<current iteration's s value>]` which is stored in `data` argument. Some time later, when user clicks on one of created `div`s it `click` handler will refer to `data` from it's lexical scope.

---

#### Further reading

- [Closures and lexical scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: Using `let` inside of the for loop is another option, since `let` is block-scoped. So you could just do `let datasrc = resulta[s].datasrc` before attaching the listener, and use `datasrc` inside of the anonymous function. `let` is not very well supported right now, however; and in Chrome, only supported in strict mode.

Comment: Aaah, also, the `y.addEventListener` line throws a SyntaxError. Should be `y.addEventListener('click', function () { location.href = data.datasrc }, false);`

Comment: Didn't see this. Good catch :) Edited.

Comment: @ gbonscinski ,can u pls explain the why data is used as an arguement and why it is inside brackets after the closure

Comment: @ChuksUdoka Here we're creating an [IIFE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) to 'store' current `resulta[s]` value in `data` because we'll need it on `click` handler execution

Comment: @ChuksUdoka I edited my answer a bit so hopefully it's more clear now